# InputObject Properties Creation

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, hashtable

I need some assistance creating a hashtable of users to use with Get-MGBetaUser

On the Microsoft Website (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0) They will give you the parameter it's looking for (UserID) but I can't find any other articles online with exact use case such as this.

Currently I can get one object in the hash and have to access it directly by asking for the Index

```
    $Users['UserID'] = @{
    UserID = "<IDOfUser>"
    }

Get-MGBetaUser -InputObject $Users.UserID
```

> If I pipe this same hash into Get-MGBetaUser, i'll get the error

```
Line |
   6 |  $Users | Get-MGBetaUser
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Resource 'System.Collections.Hashtable' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects
     | are not present.
```

[image: InputObject]

The hash will have approx. 15-20k userids which will need to be added, and they'll be coming from a CSV

It looks like Microsoft will only accept the Pipeline input through this method with the hash. Everything else I've always done will allow piping an array of IDs into it.

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I changed the title. Hope that Helps!

Comment: Your hashtable definition looks strange with the outer indexing. After looking at the documentation I think it should be just `$Users = @{ UserID = "<IDOfUser>" }`. Alternatively, if `$Users` already is a hashtable, you could do `$Users.UserID = "<IDOfUser>"` or `$Users['UserID'] = "<IDOfUser>"`. It would be helpful if you'd share more code to get an idea of the context where this is used in.

Comment: @zett42, I tried the first example you gave, `$Users = @{ UserID = "<IDOfUser>" }` and that did work, but how will I be able to add more UserIDs if that's the Param that the input object is looking for?

Comment: Because of course, it won't let me add another key called UserID. I'll add some more background code shortly.

Comment: `Import-CSV <Path> | Select-Object @{Name ="UserID"; Expression = {($_.”msDS-ExternalDirectoryObjectId”).Trim("User_")}} | ForEach-Object{
        $IDHash[$_.UserID]=@{UserID=$_.UserID}
    }
    Get-MGUser -InputObject $IDHash`

This was the test I was using, I was putting the ID as the key also so I could keep adding. The resulting ID from the Trim are known good values as I can query them independently by supplying them like `Get-MGUser -UserID <ValueInUserIDPropOfHash>`

Comment: It doesn't look like `Get-MGUser` supports a hashtable of hashtables as input. I'm still wondering why you even try something like that instead of passing each user to `Get-MgUser`, e. g. something like that: `Import-CSV <Path> | Select-Object @{Name ="UserID"; Expression = {($_.”msDS-ExternalDirectoryObjectId”).Trim("User_")}} | ForEach-Object{ Get-MGUser -UserId $_.UserId }`

Comment: Using graph, doing it that way would make an api request every time. If I can bundle the id in whatever way they’re after it will do it in bulk. I’m just not understanding how they want you to have your hash laid out. As from your example it’ll work for one but not multiple.

Comment: Am I  looking at this the wrong way? I currently have our users broken into 14 'Jobs' 14 files of 20k IDs. My plan was to pipe those users into the Get-MGUser Command but doing it as a $Users | ForEach{Get-MGUser -UserID $_} was way too slow. 

I know Graph was supposed to be able to 'batch' request, but -Inputobject was the only param that accepted pipeline input.

Comment: Use foreach : $Users.UserID | foreach { Get-MGBetaUser -InputObject $_ }  You are making request to a server and if the server does not support an array you can't bundle the requests.  You must then do it one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your responses, as it seems the answer is you couldn't supply the Graph SDK with an array or hash of users as originally intended, I opted to go a different route. The example I was giving was to have x number of jobs spin off based off the number of hashes/files I had, so that I could limit each jobs scope and create realistic timeframes for data pulls.

I decided to create an hash table of Filters which will limit each jobs exposure. In my case, we have 140k+ students, so I created a filter for each SurNames ending in A,B,C... Spinning these into 27 jobs A-Z I can get complete results back within 30 minutes. In my testing, trying to do one big pull of students took hours. The reason for doing this is I am also opting to get Licensing information along with Sign In Activity (Which requires you to supply a GUID if you used a for-each)

Allowing Graph to use the filter enables the SDK to get the data in batches, and not the other way around.

If anyone has further insight into this, or sees a better way (Other than For-Each) feel free to let me know, otherwise I'm marking this closed!